# Spinner List Item

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, oop

I'm currently working on pricing calculator in which the customer only need to select what they want from the spinner list, then the calculator will calculated the total price.

I have no prob in creating the spinner drop down list, but each item in the spinner have different value for example if spinner have "LORRY" "BUS" and "CAR" and for "LORRY" the price is 20, "CAR" is 30 and "BUS" was 10 dollar.

How can I add different values into the each spinner item. I use string array to create the drop list item. I have created on Android Studio platform.

**MainActivity.java**

```js
package com.jika.directcalc;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnervalue);
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.value));
        myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }
}
```

**String.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">DIRECTCalc</string>
    <string name="tmlogo">tmlogo</string>

    <string-array name="value">
        <item>IPV4 (16 IP)</item>
        <item>IPV6</item>
        <item>BGP</item>
        <item>Bandwith on demand</item>
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 3):

at first get the value from spinner

`int value = 0;
String Text = String.valueOf(mySpinner.getSelectedItem());`

then assign the value e.g.

`if(Text == "BUS"){
 value = 20;
}`

Comment: use equals() method to compare to strings.

Answer (score 1):

When You need while calculating the total, use **`getSelectedItem()`** or

**`getSelectedItemPosition()`**

```
String text = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
switch(text)
{
    case "LORRY" : value=20;break;
    case "CAR"   : value=30;break;
    case "BUS" : value=10;break;
}
```

You can use position too.

```
switch(mSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition())
{
  //cases
}
```

If you want to get immediately when the Item is selected, **`Use listener`**

```
mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        switch(position)
        {
        case 0 : value=20;break;
        case 1 : value=30;break;
        case 2 : value=10;break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a list of data that you want the spinner to display

```
    List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerArray.add("item1");
    spinnerArray.add("item2");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    sItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also to find out what is selected you could do something like this

```
    String selected = sItems.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (selected.equals("what ever the option was")) {

    }
```